# Rotation of axes transformation as definition of vectors

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, tensors, vectors

Given a three-axes coordinate system ${1,2,3} $ by the right-hand rule, and a new coordinate system ${1',2',3'}$ , I know that one can define a vector $\vec{x}$ to be something that obeys the following transformation rule:

If $(x_1 , x_2 ,x_3 )$ are its locations in the system 1,2,3 , and $(x_1 ' ,x_2 ' ,x_3 ' ) $ are its locations in the system 1',2',3' then: 
$x_i = \ell _{ij} x_j ' $ (I used here Einstein's summation convention) [where $\ell_{ij}$ is the angle between old axis i and new axis j' ] .

I never understood this property. Can someone please explain to me how can I derive this transformation ? (i.e.- how can I show geometrically that a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3 $ is indeed a vector)

In addition, how can one prove the identity $\ell_{ij} \ell_{ik} = \delta _{jk} $ without using the identity I mentioned above ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean to say $\ell_{ij}$ is the rotation matrix between the two sets of bases?  Your description of $\ell_{ij}$ and its components seems unclear.

Comment: Yes . I want to know how to prove that the rotation matrix is all cosine, without using algebraic arguments. Only geometry

Comment: But, a rotation matrix has both sines and cosines...

Comment: Please take a look at page 8 here:
http://www.ce.udel.edu/faculty/kaliakin/appendix_tensors.pdf
I mean that if we take one coordinate system, and rotate it, the coordinates should be transformed by the cosines of the angles between the old and new axes... Hope you will be able to help me now